# Making list items width adjust dynamically to occupy the whole list width size

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is pull few strings from a server,
and then create buttons as the number of strings, 
the buttons must occupy the whole screen (Horizontally).
problem is each time I get different data so items width must be dynamic

I've tried to put weights to the items but it doesn't work.
is it possible to achieve such a thing with a list?

EDIT:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/gameTypeList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

this is my item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="0"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/gameTypeButton"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Post your xml layout here.

Comment: The number of buttons is dynamic also? If so, you will need to create the Buttons dynamically (programmatically), not using a static layout like this.

Comment: Put android:orientation="horizontal"